# My server gets overloaded even though I keep a limit on the requests I send it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, heroku

I have a server on Heroku - 3 dynos, 2 processes each.

The server does 2 things:

1. It responds to requests from the browser (AJAX and some web pages), based on data stored in a postgresql database
2. It exposes a REST API to update the data in the database. This API is called by another server. The rate of calls is limited: The other server only calls my server through a queue with a single worker, which makes sure the other server doesn't issue more than one request in parallel to my server (I verified that indeed it doesn't).

When I look at new relic, I see the following graph, which suggests that even though I keep the other server at one parallel request at most, it still loads my server which creates peaks.

[image: response time]

I'd expect that since the rate of calls from the other server is limited, my server will not get overloaded, since a request will only start when the previous request ended (I'm guessing that maybe the database gets overloaded if it gets an update request and returns but continue processing after that).

- What can explain this behaviour?
- Where else can I look at in order to understand what's going on?
- Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

There are whole lot of directions this investigation could go, but from your screenshot and some inferences, I have two guesses.

- **A long query**—You'd see this graph if your other server or a browser occasionally hits a slow query. If it's just a long read query and your DB isn't hitting its limits, it should only affect the process running the query, but if the query is taking an exclusive lock, all dynos will have to wait on it. Since the spikes are so regular, first think of anything you have running on a schedule - if the cadence matches, you probably have your culprit. The next simple thing to do is run `heroku pg:long-running-queries` and `heroku pg:seq-scans`. The former shows queries that might need optimization, and the latter shows full table scans you can probably fix with a different query or a better index. You can find similar information in NewRelic's Database tab, which has time and throughput graphs you can try to match agains your queueing spikes. Finally, look at NewRelic's Transactions tab.

  - There are various ways to sort - slowest average response time is probably going to help, but check out all the options and see if any transactions stand out.
  - Click on a suspicious transaction and look at the graph on the right. If you see spikes matching your queueing buildups, that could be it, but since it looks to be affecting your whole site, watch out for several transactions seeing correlated slowdowns.
  - Check out the transaction traces at the bottom. Something in there taking a long time to run is as close to a smoking gun as you'll get. This should correlate with `pg:long-running-queries`.
  - Look at the breakdown table between the graph and the transaction traces. Check for things that are taking a long time (eg. a 2 second external request) or happening often (eg, a partial that gets rendered 2500 times per request). Those are places for caching or optimization.
- **Garbage collection**—This is less likely because Ruby GCs all the time and there's no reason it would show spikes on that regular cadence, *but* if there's a regular request that allocates a ton of objects, both building the objects and cleaning them up will take time. It would only affect one dyno at once, and it would be correlated with a long or highly repetitive query in your NewRelic investigation. You can see some stats about this in NewRelic's Ruby VM tab.

Take a look at your dyno and DB memory usage too. Both are printed to the [Heroku logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-metrics-logs), and if you add [Librato](https://addons.heroku.com/librato), they'll build some automatic graphs that are quite helpful. If your dyno is swapping, performance will suffer and you should either upgrade to a bigger dyno or run fewer processes per dyno. Processes will typically accumulate memory as they run and never quite release as much as you'd like, so tune it so that right before a restart, your dyno is just under its available RAM. Similarly for the DB, if you're hitting swap there, query performance will suffer and you should upgrade.

Other things it could be, but probably isn't in this case:

- **Sleeping dynos**—Heroku puts a dyno to sleep if it hasn't served a request in a while, but only if you have just 1 dyno running. You have 3, so this isn't it.
- **Web Server Concurrency**—If at any given moment, there are more requests than available processes, requests will be queued. The obvious fix is to increase the available dynos/processes, which will put more load on your DB and potentially move the issue there. Since some regular request is visible every time, I'm guessing request volume is low and this also isn't your problem.
- **Heroku Instability**—Sometimes, for no obvious reason, Heroku starts queueing requests more than it should and doesn't report any issues at [status.heroku.com](http://status.heroku.com). Restarting the dynos typically fixes that temporarily while Heroku gets their head back on straight.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Indeed the other server runs on a scheduler, it acquires data every hour and updates my server, which means it makes many calls (one at a time as explained above). These are the spikes you see in the graph. There are no long queries in there, only a couple of simple finds and an update. What bothers me is that the other server overloads mine hourly, even though it only posts through a single-worker queue.

Comment: How many requests are coming in when the other server isn't active? If there are many and they're typically very fast, a bunch of updates could be relatively slow as well as invalidate the DB cache, causing worse performance as it warms back up.

Comment: When the other server isn't active my server only answers requests from browsers. Typically ~100 RPM. It seems the time my server spends on those request is negligible in comparison with the calls from the other server. Browsers just request data. All of the updates are a result of calls from the other server.

Comment: So even if your update server is running in serial, if it's doing in the order of 1 request/second, that's a 50% load increase on your DB. Especially if the browsers are reading the data that's being updated, that would explain a slowdown as they wait behind the write query. The spikes over 1-3 seconds still seem funny to me. Try reducing your query plan threshold (Settings>Application) to see if anything comes over the line. You could also sleep your worker to slow it down further and maybe resolve a particular kind of update that's causing lots of work.

Comment: An interesting observation from looking at the queues on the other server -- the peaks happen just when the other server starts sending in data, however, the peaks end after a few minutes even though the other server continues to send in data much longer (!). I'm not sure what that means but it may hint at something. In addition I can see that the updates themselves are slow, less so the reads from browsers.

Comment: Slowness after an update sounds a lot to me like cache invalidation. I think Heroku has some DB cache statistics in the logs or via the CLI.

Comment: Oops, I read your sentence backwards on my phone. If your app gets slow when the new kind of requests (updates) start coming in, then speeds up even as they continue, it could be memory allocation/swap. Check your dyno's RAM usage.